# How to get a segmented picker to scroll horizontally in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to have have a horizontal ScrollView to function as a horizontal picker with a segmented picker style while still being scrollable.

I have tried two things...

1. I have made a Horizontal ScrollView with buttons but wasn't able to figure out how that could possibly work once more groups would be added.  Also didn't know how to make the selected button I pressed standout
2. I made a Horizontal `PickerView` and gave it the `.segmented` picker style then moved it into a Horizontal ScrollView. This does not scroll...

```
// Horizontal Picker inside of a Horizontal ScrollView

var groups = ["Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3", "Group 4", "Group 5", "Group 6"]

Form {
   Section {
      ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
         Picker("Pick A Group", selection: $group) {
            ForEach(groups, id: \.self) {
               Text($0)
            }
         }.pickerStyle(.segmented)
      }
      Text("You selected: \(group)")
   }
```

So I ask how would I make this scrollable?

Answer (score 1):

A segmented picker inherently has a pan gesture that allows the user to drag the "selection rectangle" along the options. This is also used to allow the user to select a different option, while they have their finger touching an option. You cannot distinguish this gesture from the gesture of "scrolling" the scroll view.

I would just add a some empty space around the picker. This way the user can pan on the empty space below the picker to scroll. You can do this either by adding a `Spacer` in a `VStack`, or add some `padding`.

```
Picker("Pick A Group", selection: $group) {
    ForEach(groups, id: \.self) {
        Text($0)
    }
}
.padding(.bottom, 30)
.pickerStyle(.segmented)
```